# Update JSON field in MYSQL

Tags: mysql, json

I need to update mysql field with updated JSON value.

```
$sampleJSON = {
   "key1":"value1",
   "key2":{
       "key3":"value3"
}
```

I would like to replace the existing JSON object present in the database column with the newer one. How is this possible using MYSQL 8.0

}

Comment: what is the data type of your column ?is it a json field

Comment: Yes, it's JSON field.

Comment: A couple of options that may be useful: [JSON_REPLACE()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json-modification-functions.html#function_json-replace) and [JSON_SET()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json-modification-functions.html#function_json-set).